# Call Ghostscript in Windows by its invocation name?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, ghostscript

What should I do to be able to call Ghostscript in Windows by its invocation name?
I added Ghostscript bin folder to Windows PATH and Path variables but it doesn't work,
neither does 'gswin32c.exe' nor 'gswin32c'. Logging out and then logging back in also didn't help.
How do I solve this issue? Maybe I'm using the wrong invocation name?

Comment: it will help if you post exactly what you are doing, and what, if any error messages  you get. Good luck.

Comment: Try to log out/log in after editing the PATH variable. At least restart cmd.

Comment: I've finaly got what i want after rebooting. Weird. Thanks all of you for your willing to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finaly got what i want after rebooting. Weird. Thanks all of you for your help.

Comment: I had to add the bin directory of the gs at the beginning of the Path variable. I did not have to restart  my system. I just restarted cmd for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 16):

There are several possibilities. To list the two most frequent ones:

1. `c:\full\path\to\gswin32c.exe` should always work.
    For 64bit systems, use `c:\full\path\to\gswin64c.exe`.
2. After a fresh installation using a standard windows installer, you may need to reboot before the updated `%path%` environment variable is used.
3. Open a `cmd` window and (assuming your Ghostscript installation ended up in `c:\path\to\gs`...) then type `set path=c:\path\to\gs\gs9.02\bin;%path%`. From this same cmd window you can now simply use `gswin32c` to start Ghostscript (use `gswin64c` on 64 bit Windows)...

Comment: I previously tried using "gs ...", but actually, "gswin64c ..." works for me. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the easiest option that actually made it work was renaming the main exe to **gs.exe** and with the path configured it works like a charm.

Comment: Quick and dirty. Thanks. I made a copy of `gswin64c.exe` and renamed it to `gs.exe`.

Comment: Sometimes quick and dirty is the only option :) @ztom